# Чего не может сделать Flutter хорошо?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Я начинающий мобильный разработчик под Андроид. Часто слышу о том, что Flutter очень крутой SDK и что он будущее мобильной разработки. Почитал много статей вроде flutter всем нравится. Мало кто пишет о недостатках этой среды, ограничиваются только туманными фразами вроде - "90% приложений могут быть разработанны на Flutter". А что же это за оставшиеся 10%, которые не могут быть разработаны?
Так же смущает количество вакансий на текущий момент, например по Санкт-Петербургу: на Flutter - 76 вакансий, на андроид разработку - 760. Почему так мало вакансий под flutter?
Конечно, у Flutter очень много плюсов, но хотелось бы и о минусах узнать.
Пожалуйста, если у кого-нибудь есть отрицательный опыт с Flutter - поделитесь.

Comment: Таких чудо SDK уже было и наверное еще будет много. Все они имеют право на жизнь, и пока ни один не покорил мир.  С React Native уже все успокоились, и тут пена спадет, увидим что будет в остатке. А вам советую, учите платформу. На чем для нее разрабатывать не имеет значения.

Comment: Основной минус, когда нужно обратится к нативному "функционалу" для которого нет полностью покрывающей библиотеки Flutter. Пример: Text to speech - (нужно проговорить текст) в библиотеке Flutter доступны не все функции (в отличие от Java) А те что есть, - вынуждают работать с костылями. Аналогичная ситуация может повториться с Камерой, акселерометром и т.п.

Answer (score 4):

— Библиотек меньше, чем для нативной разработки

— Конечный установочный пакет больше, так как в него добавляется виртуальная машина Dart

— Интерфейс создается с помощью кода, из-за чего грань между логикой и дизайном гораздо тоньше

— Библиотек (и информации) меньше, чем для нативной разработки

— Нестабильность (совсем недавно вышел из beta)